# How can i make settings in router to block certain websites during office hours?

Tags: firewall, proxy, filtering

My company wants to restrict access to some websites during office hours. How this can be achieved using Router or any other technique?

Comment: what type of firewall are you using and how large of a company?

Comment: Basically you can't with basic router alone, if you want to block larger sites like facebook, as facebook servers are in multiple networks. Or you can, but it's really hard to maintain it.

Comment: @pablo  Fyi My company has around 150-200 employees, as we are a growing company we would like to have these policies.

Comment: @ Olli if its not with router what would you recommend to achieve this?

Comment: what firewall do you have?

Comment: @pablo its cyberoam

Comment: You've included the tag 'proxy' which implies that you are using a proxy server for all web traffic, so why are you even considering blocking individual sites via a firewall? It will be dificult (if not impossible to maintain). See ooshro's answer below, which will do exactly what you want using a proxy server.

Comment: @olli  You could do this with the router alone, with the right router and OS.

Comment: @jgbelacqua it was tagged [cisco] as i believed it can be done using some iOS programming on my cisco router

Comment: @jgbelacqua can you suggest some idea to do it that way?
@bryan i didnt set 'proxy' tab, i guess it was edited by 'sysadmin' :)

Comment: @sharjeel Sure.  Try [Time-Based Access Lists Using Time Ranges](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0t/12_0t1/feature/guide/timerang.html) . Time-based ACLs were introduced in Cisco IOS Software Release 12.0.1.T. 
@olli This doc shows how it would work for some Cisco devices.

Comment: That being said, depending on your site and topology, and where you are logging to or managing configurations from, the answers involving squidguard or (implicitly) cyberoam might make more sense for you.  All things being equal, priority for me would be maintainability.

Comment: thanks jgbelacqua!! as your answer is a part of comment, i cant mark that as answer :(
can you make that as reply, so i can do mark it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Time-Based Access Lists Using Time Ranges](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0t/12_0t1/feature/guide/timerang.html) .

This doc shows how it would work for some Cisco devices. 
Time-based ACLs were introduced in Cisco IOS Software Release 12.0.1.T.

With that being said, depending on your site and topology, and where you are logging to or managing configurations from, the answers involving squidguard or (implicitly) cyberoam might make more sense for you. All things being equal, priority for me would be maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

I use [squidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/). SquidGuard is a URL redirector used to use blacklists with the proxysoftware Squid.

My squidGuard.conf:

```
time workhours {
     weekly mtwhf 09:00 - 18:00
}

...

acl {

     clients within workhours {
         pass     !hacking !violence !proxy !porn !mail !warez !gambling !drugs !audio-video !aggressive !paramon !redirector !suspect all
     } else {
         pass     any
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at your firewalls website it looks like it can do this.

http://www.cyberoam.com/webfiltering.html

If you can provide more information on your firewall model/configuration I may be able to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a web filtering server using Websense or McAfee Smartfilter. Both of these products are compatible with Cisco devices. Both are able to setup different policies based on time of day. The great thing about these solutions is that they require very little maintenance after they're setup. The URL lists are automatically updated as long as your subscription is valid. Here's a Cisco article that details setting this up on an IOS based router:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t15/feature/guide/ftwebsen.html